# How to optimize filtering of a layer in QGS API

Tags: python, filter, qgis

I'm developping a QGIS plugin (under version 2.8.1) for traffic assignment where I want to show the results of my simulation at each time step. Right now I'm using Time Manager plugin but it gets very slow when my layer has hundreds of thousands of attributes. In my case I know exactly what feature IDs I want to show at each time step so I thought it would be easy to make it faster.

Here is what I tried (sorry of my way of python programming but I'm quite new using this language): at each time step of my loop I set the ordered list of     indexes of attributes to show (they are always ordered in my case).

```
# TEST 1 -----------------------------------
for step in time_steps:
            index_start = my_list_of_indexes_start[step]
            index_end = my_list_of_indexes_end[step]
            expression = 'fid >= ' + str(index_start) + ' AND fid <= ' + str(index_end)
            # Or for optimization tests
            # expression = '"FIELD_TIME"' + "=" + str(step)
            layer_dynamic.setSubsetString(expression)
            self.iface.mapCanvas().refresh()                
            time.sleep(0.2)
# TEST 2 ------------------------------------
for step in time_steps:
            index_start = my_list_of_indexes_start[step]
            index_end = my_list_of_indexes_end[step]
            indexes = list(j for j in range(index_start, index_end))
            request = QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterFids(indexes)
            layer_dynamic.getFeatures(request)
            self.iface.mapCanvas().refresh()                
            time.sleep(0.2)
```

Solution 1 with

```
layer_dynamic.setSubsetString(expression)
```

works as it refresh the view with the correct filtered features displayed on canvas at each time step but it is even slower than using a SQL expression not based on the indexes but on attributes values (as shown in comment in TEST 1 loop).

Solution 2 with

```
layer_dynamic.getFeatures(request)
```

is fast but the display of the layer doesn't change.
Any idea why?

Answer (score 2):

The method

```
bool QgsVectorLayer.setSubsetString(self, QString subset)
```

filters the layer (more details in [setSubsetString](http://geoapis.sourcepole.com/qgispyapi/qgsvectorlayer#QgsVectorLayer.setSubsetString)), so only the features that match the filter (provided using a SQL statement or other definition string the the "subset" QString) "will belong to the layer" after it's being filtered. Thus, when you call refresh, only the filtered features are displayed.

On the other hand, the method

```
QgsFeatureIterator QgsVectorLayer.getFeatures(self, QgsFeatureRequest request=QgsFeatureRequest())
```

returns a iterator for the features matching you request (more details in [getFeatures](http://geoapis.sourcepole.com/qgispyapi/qgsvectorlayer#QgsVectorLayer.getFeatures)). It doesn't filter the layer. Using the iterator, you just iterate over the features matching the request.